# finding all simple paths between two points of a graph with cycles

Tags: graph, path

I am trying to compute all simple paths between two nodes.
I tried DFS and it seems DFS will not work.

The following figure make my goal more clear.

[image]

two nodes 'a' and 'f' is given, and have to find paths between them.
for above example, there are two simple paths:

a ->b ->c ->e ->f

a ->b ->d ->e ->f

I checked some posts, but they seems don't handle cycles( without cycles my DFS works).

The graph is undirected and has cycles. I believe there is a solution for this.
could anyone point me a reliable algorithm ? 
it would be great if such algorithm comes with pseudocode.

Thanks in advance
Best,

Comment: Actually, you could just do recursive DFS, but giving always as parameter the visited nodes and making sure you don't dig deeper into nodes you have already visited in your current DFS path (thus, avoiding cycles). Notice how this is different from the global visited list, since it wouldn't allow you to visit the same node more than once.

Comment: Oh, and as a plus, the visited list you carry on, is exactly the path you need right when you find the final node.

Comment: my bad that i should mention is that I tried non-recursive DFS. but the problem is when find one simple paths in above figure {a ->b ->c ->e ->f}, then you look for second path but 'e' become visited already, so can not go further. does recursive DFS solve this?

Comment: Dear Andras Gyomrey, what you mean is that the problem of not being able to visit a same node second time in non-recursive DFS can be avoided in a recursive DFS?  is there a way to do it with non-recursive DFS?

Comment: If you don't use a global `visited` list, but pass it as a parameter (not by reference) to your recursive calls. This means modifications to the `visited` list are local to the current function invokation. Once the **recursive call ends**, everything that call flagged as visited is forgotten, which allows you to visit the same node again through another recursive call.

Comment: what if I use non-recursive DFS ? how to with the visited set in this case?

Comment: Just flag the current node as unvisited at the end of the iteration so it can be visited again through another dfs path.

Comment: Sorry for asking too much, could you provide pseudo-code for non-recursive one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Ruby solution using a weighted adj matrix and avoiding cycles. It is a little messy but it seams to work.
I'm testing with a graph with nodes a,b,c,d,e,f in a connection loop (like a ring) but with two extra connections (b <-> f and c <-> f) generating cycles to test the algorithm.

```
# Generate all paths from A to E
@grapascii =
'
   C-----D
  / \    |
 B---F---E
  \ /     
   A
'

@nodes = %w{A B C D E F}
n = -1 # represents no connection

#weighted adj matrix
@adjmat = [
    #a  b  c  d  e  f
    [n, 1, n, n, n, 1], # a
    [1, n, 3, n, n, 1], # b
    [n, 4, n, 2, n, 1], # c
    [n, n, 4, n, 1, n], # d
    [n, n, n, 1, n, 1], # e
    [1, 6, 1, n, 2, n]  # f
]

# generate a neighbors hash for easy and fast future acccess
def gen_neighbors(nodes, adjmat)
    len = nodes.length
    neighbors = {}
    for i in 0..(len - 1)
        for j in 0..(len - 1)
            if adjmat[i][j] >= 0 && i != j
                neighbors[nodes[i]] ||= []
                neighbors[nodes[i]] << {:node => nodes[j], :cost => adjmat[i][j]}
            end
        end
    end
    return neighbors
end

@neighbors = gen_neighbors(@nodes, @adjmat)

def all_paths(currpath, destnode, currcost, paths)
    #the current node is always tha last one on the current evaluated path
    currnode = currpath.last
    # just the neighbors that is nor on the current evaluated path, to avoid cycles
    current_neighbors = @neighbors[currnode].select{|n| !currpath.include?(n[:node])}

    #each neighbor is a hash with :node and :cost
    current_neighbors.each do |neighbor|
        # yes. we have to duplicate that. maybe there is a better solution...
        new_path = currpath + [neighbor[:node]]
        cost = currcost + neighbor[:cost]

        if neighbor[:node] == destnode
            #FOUND PATH
            paths << {:path => new_path, :cost => cost}
        else
            all_paths(new_path, destnode, cost, paths)
        end
    end
end

puts @grapascii

puts "NEIGHBORS HASH:"
@neighbors.each do |node, neighbors|
    neighbors_and_cost = neighbors.map{|n| "#{n[:node]}(#{n[:cost]})"}
    puts "#{node} => #{neighbors_and_cost.join(', ')}"
end


# start path with the start node
startpath = ['A']
# paths variable will hold all possible paths without cycles
paths = []
all_paths(startpath, 'E', 0, paths)

puts "PATHS:"
# sort paths by total cost(optional)
paths.sort!{|a, b| a[:cost] <=> b[:cost]}
paths.each do |path|
    puts "#{path[:path]} => #{path[:cost]}"
end
```

## Output:

```
   C-----D
  / \    |
 B---F---E
  \ /     
   A
NEIGHBORS HASH:
A => B(1), F(1)
B => A(1), C(3), F(1)
C => B(4), D(2), F(1)
D => C(4), E(1)
E => D(1), F(1)
F => A(1), B(6), C(1), E(2)
PATHS:
["A", "F", "E"] => 3
["A", "B", "F", "E"] => 4
["A", "F", "C", "D", "E"] => 5
["A", "B", "F", "C", "D", "E"] => 6
["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"] => 7
["A", "B", "C", "F", "E"] => 7
["A", "F", "B", "C", "D", "E"] => 13
```